# the program should translate numbers into letters. How to?

Tags: c#, console

My code should translate letters into numbers. How to translate numbers into letters?

```
string strs = Console.ReadLine();
                Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>
        {
            {'A', 1},
            {'B', 2},
            {'C', 3},

        };

                for (int i = 0; i < strs.Length; i++)
                {
                    int val = 0;
                    if (dic.TryGetValue(strs[i], out val))
                        strs = strs.Replace(strs[i].ToString(), val.ToString());
                }



                Console.WriteLine(strs);
```

Comment: Please specify your string for better understanding

Comment: what should your output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All characters are in a computer mapped to a numeric value. So to get the numeric value of a character you can do the following:

```
int valueOfA= 'A';
```

Turns out that it is 65. So the following will work:

```
var text = "ABBA";
foreach (var character in text.ToCharArray())
{
    int result=character;
    Console.WriteLine(result-64);
}
```

for lowercase it is 33. So if you need to handle all a's as 1 then you can use:

```
var text = "aBBA".ToUpper();
foreach (var character in text.ToCharArray())
{
    int result=character;
    Console.WriteLine(result-64);
}
```

otherwise you need to do some checks.

Also notice that the character for 1 is not necessarily the value of 1. (in fact it is -15)

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not need to use a dictionary for this. It can be done relatively easily just using the `char` type and the `int` type. Note that this assumes your example always uses upper-case characters from A-Z. If you need something more robust than this, you'll obviously need more complex logic.

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static int? ConvertToInt(char value, char lowerLimit, char upperLimit)
    {
        // If the value provided is outside acceptable ranges, then just return
        // null. Note the int? signature - nullable integer. You could also swap
        // this with 0.
        if (value < lowerLimit || value > upperLimit)
            return null;

        // 'A' is 65. Substracting 64 gives us 1.
        return ((int)value) - 64;
    }

    public static char? ConvertToChar(int value, int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
    {
        // Basically the same as above, but with char? instead of int?
        if (value < lowerLimit || value > upperLimit)
            return null;

        // 'A' is 65. Substracting 64 gives us 1.
        return ((char)value) + 64;
    }
}
```

Usage would look something like this:

```
// = 1
int? a = Converter.ConvertToInt('A', 'A', 'F');
char? A = Converter.ConvertToChar(a, 1, (int)('F' - 'A'));
```

Note that you would need to do some level of string indexing, but this gives you a nice structure in that you don't need to store any state anywhere - you can just make it part of your method invocation.